# user control doesn't get displayed in another user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have made a user control as report .Now this control has a button on whose click another user control is being called.the values gets passed correctly,also gets binded to the grid ..but finally the second control doesn't get displayed on the screen .I can't paste my code here since it is very long.am i missing out nothing for interaction between two user controls?

Comment: You'll have to provide some code samples. How are you binding it to the grid?

Comment: actually the second control is working fine if used directly on the page ..but when i am embedding it into a user control and then tryig to display it is not showing anything..infact the grid has the values and everything just it is not getting displayed and my control is a grid itself with some inbuilt features like paging and sorting

Comment: Still, can you post how you are using your control in the grid? Are you using it declaratively in a templated column? Are you loading it dynamically in a RowDataBound event?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099603/loading-nested-usercontrols-in-asp-net

Comment: How you are adding this second user control, dynamically or statically?

Answer (score 0):

try to check the BringToFront method, 
have a look on this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winforms/thread/B977EB66-D8A5-4CC6-AB83-38E0C80C71D3)